# JAVA: Fastest way to download multiple files at once?

Tags: java, download

I have written a "crawler", that has the option of specifying the number of "threads".  The idea is that if the user specifies 5 threads, the crawler will actually try to download 5 web pages in one go. In other words, I need:

- the fastest way,
- to download MULTIPLE HTML pages
- in Java

But it must also:

- Be able to tell me the response code (200, 404 etc)
- Determine the MIME type --> preferably by only getting the headers (so I dont have to download an entire 100 Mb file only to find out it's HTML)

In PHP I would consider things like Curl, or Guzzle and in some cases maybe even "file_get_contents". However, I don't know what the fastest way would be in Java. Can anyone please tell me?

Comment: Use a `ExecutorService` of some kind - Also, what have you tried so far?  Have you tried downloading a single page?  Does each page have their own additional threads to deal with things like images, scripts and CSS resources?

Comment: Right now I don't need to download the images, css etc. The scaper is only grabbing the actual HTML pages. That is why I need a way to check the "type" of file, so only HTML/TEXT can be considered.